# Calculated Member over two date dimensions

Tags: ssas, mdx

I have at current the, calculated member

```
create member [017SKY_DATAWAREHOUSE].[Measures].[ConversionTest]
as
([Measures].[Lead Count]
,[Origin].[Origin].[Origin Sale Type Description].&[Sky].&[Direct Referral]
,[Misc Flag].[Sale Flag].&[True])
/
([Measures].[Lead Count]
,[Origin].[Origin].[Origin Sale Type Description].&[Sky].&[Direct Referral]),
format_string = "percent"
```

However I need to numerator of this member to act over one date dimension, and the denominator to act over another date dimension, that is if I cut this Calculated member by date dimension A I need the numerator to be cut by data dimension B.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function LinkMember is the suitable to do this.

```
(
[Measures].[Lead Count]
,[Origin].[Origin].[Origin Sale Type Description].&[Sky].&[Direct Referral]
LinkMember([Date].[Date].[July 1, 2002], [Date].[Calendar])
)
```

Comment: That looks promising! So I'm going to be cutting this calculated member by the 'Created Date' and the numerator would act over the 'Sale Date' so am I correct to do something like this:

`create member [017SKY_DATAWAREHOUSE].[Measures].[ConversionTest]
as
([Measures].[Lead Count]
,[Origin].[Origin].[Origin Sale Type Description].&[Sky].&[Direct Referral]
,LinkMember([Created On Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,[Sale Date].[Calendar]))
/
([Measures].[Lead Count]
,[Origin].[Origin].[Origin Sale Type Description].&[Sky].&[Direct Referral])
,format_string = "percent"`